# Creating a test case from exploratory session in Microsoft test manager only shows last 10 steps

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

Exploratory test sessions seem like a great tool to generate certain types of tests cases; having a recording of the session is very useful, and a single click to create a new test case with most information pre-filled is a great time saver.

However, when I hit 'Create Test Case', only the last ten steps are shown. Often, I'll need more than that, and I'm not able to figure out how to change the number recorded. The 'Change settings' dialog only lets me adjust the screenshot tool and audio recording settings, and the only option available when the testing is started are build and environment selections.

How can I record more than the last ten steps in a new test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default value. If you click on the Change Steps button you can select more steps there.  In addition you can change the default by editing mtm.exe.config on your machine. It can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` by default.

Thanks to [this article](http://donovanbrown.com/post/I-only-see-the-last-10-steps-of-my-Exploratory-Testing-in-MTM-when-I-create-a-test-case) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300009/MTM-11-Configuration-Settings-Customization-Troubl).